# Is string comparison faster than string length?

Tags: javascript, string, performance, comparison, string-comparison

I am unsure of which of these ways is faster to use multiple times, testing with a lot of string variables.
Which of these is faster to use for checking if the string is just whitespace?

```
if (str.trim().length > 0) {

}
```

Or

```
if (str.trim() !== '') {

}
```

Comment: It won't make a difference. Before arguing otherwise, please construct a [jfperf](http://jsperf.com) test-case. Then realize any such microbenchmarks - even if they show a "big difference" - are usually completely irrelevant in a larger context.

Comment: Thank you! I've never heard of this site before.

Comment: Javascript question marked as a duplicate of a .NET one? :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, why not test it? http://jsperf.com/empty-string-comparison2

In terms of calculations per second, they differ by less than 1% (at least on Chromium). Unless you're testing millions of strings every second, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "benchmark and find out!". If you do this, you can also try using a regexp and see how fast that is:

```
if (str.match(/^\s*$/))
```

Comment: Short answer or comment .. about the same.

Comment: Since we're preoptimizing, shouldn't this be `/^\s*$/.test(str)`? Surely it's faster to return a boolean than a result array! ;)

Answer (score 2):

According to this fast test regular expression as Alex D suggested is faster.

```
string = "   l   l l sfsf  __ ";
d = new Date().getTime();
for(var i = 0; i < 900000; i++){
    if (string.trim().length > 0) continue;
}
d1 = new Date().getTime() - d;
alert(d1);
d = new Date().getTime();
for(var i = 0; i < 900000; i++){
    if (string.trim() !== '') continue;
}
d1 = new Date().getTime() - d;
alert(d1);
d = new Date().getTime();
for(var i = 0; i < 900000; i++){
    if (string.match(/^\s*$/)) continue;
}
d1 = new Date().getTime() - d;
alert(d1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe String Lenght comparison is faster as compare to comparison of two strings.

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/pja77gzp/

```
<script>
    var s1 = '  ';
    var s2 = '  ';
    var benchmarkCount = 10000000;
    function testStringComparison() {
        var t = new Date();
        var i = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < benchmarkCount; i++) {
            if (s1.trim().length == s2.trim().length) {
                i++;
            }
        }
        t = (new Date()) - t;
        document.writeln("testStringComparison completed");
        document.writeln(t);
    }

    function testStringLenght() {
        var t = new Date();
        var i = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < benchmarkCount; i++) {
            if (s1.trim() == s1.trim()) {
                i++;
            }
        }
        t = (new Date()) - t;
        document.writeln("testStringLenght completed");
        document.writeln(t);
    }


    function startBenchmark() {
        testStringComparison(); 
        testStringLenght();
    }

    setTimeout(startBenchmark, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for setting this up, but you didn't post any test results. I did some tests with this and got some very interesting results. Most of the time the length comparison was actually slower, by a little bit. Even when the strings were very long and almost identical. In fact, strangely it seemed that making the string longer actually made the length comparison even slower. Then I tried comparing the strings '222222' and '2' and this time the full string comparison took almost twice as long as the length comparison!

Comment: @Moss absolutely correct. I updated the jsfiddle link for the benchmark. I believe its the length comparison which should be used by everyone if performance plays a major role in their app. Specially for large calculations.